# Filtering conversation by filter type and value

Tags: java

I have been assigned to developed a feature that filters a conversation. For example, I want to filter the conversation by user id then export it to something either JSON or text file. In this case, I created a class that handles the filters like this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Represents the filter that operates the filter functions for messages
 *
 * @author Muhammad
 */
public class Filter {

    String filterType;
    String argumentValue;

    //Constructor that takes a parameter of filter type and argument value.
    public Filter(String filterType, String argumentValue) {
        this.filterType = filterType;
        this.argumentValue = argumentValue;
    }

    //Method that filters a conversation by a specific user and return filterd conversation.
    public static Conversation filterByUser(Conversation conversation, String specificUser) {
        List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Filter by used id
        for (Message message : conversation.messages) {
            if (message.senderId.equals(specificUser)) {
                messageList.add(message);
                Conversation filteredConversation = new Conversation(conversation.name, messageList);
                conversation = filteredConversation;
            }
        }
        return conversation;
    }

    //Method that filters a conversation that contains a specific keywod and returns filterd conversation.
    public static Conversation filterByWord(Conversation conversation, String specificWord) {
        List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Filter by keyword
        for (Message message : conversation.messages) {
            if (message.content.contains(specificWord)) {
                messageList.add(message);
                Conversation filteredConversation = new Conversation(conversation.name, messageList);
                conversation = filteredConversation;
            }
        }
        return conversation;
    }

    //Method that hides a word in a conversation by a specificword
    public static Conversation hideWord(Conversation conversation, String specificWord) {
        List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Filter by used id
        for (Message message : conversation.messages) {
            if (message.content.contains(specificWord)) {
                message.content = message.content.replaceAll(specificWord, "*redacted*");
                messageList.add(message);
                Conversation filteredConversation = new Conversation(conversation.name, messageList);
                conversation = filteredConversation;
            }
        }
        return conversation;
    }
}
```

In another class, I used it inside a method called filter like this.

```
private void filter(Filter filter, Conversation conversation, String outputFilePath) throws Exception {

        String filterType = filter.filterType; //used to get the type of filter
        String argumentValue = filter.argumentValue;

        //Filterers
        switch (filterType) {
            case "filteruser":
                conversation = Filter.filterByUser(conversation, argumentValue);
                this.writeConversation(conversation, outputFilePath);
                break;
            case "filterword":
                conversation = Filter.filterByWord(conversation, argumentValue);
                this.writeConversation(conversation, outputFilePath);
                break;
            case "hideword":
                conversation = Filter.hideWord(conversation, argumentValue);
                this.writeConversation(conversation, outputFilePath);
                break;
            default:
                this.writeConversation(conversation, outputFilePath);
                break;
        }

    }
```

This code works, however I'd like feedback on anyways that I can improve the code as I am just a graduate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to mention only one thing especially:

You're using "magic string" to choose your filter types. Instead of doing that (because it's brittle) you are probably better off with an enum:

```
public enum FilterType {
    USER, WORD, HIDE_WORD
}
```

Your code would have to adjust a little, but to give a short look into the filter method:

```
private void filter(Filter filter, Conversation conversation, String outputFilePath) {
    switch (filter.filterType) {
        case FilterType.USER:
            conversation = Filter.filterByUser(conversation, filter.argumentValue);
            writeConversation(conversation, outputFilePath);
            break;
        case FilterType.WORD:
            conversation = Filter.filterByWord(conversation filter.argumentValue);
            writeConversation(conversation, outputFilePath);
            break;
        // ...
```

This exposes another small improvement possibility in your code.

In every case you will call `this.writeConversation` with exactly the same arguments. You can move that to outside the switch-case block:

```
switch (filter.filterType) {
    // ...
}
this.writeConversation(conversation, outputFilePath);
```

Another last thing I want to recommend is using `Path` intead of `String` to refer to `outputFilePath`. This makes it blatantly obvious, that you're  actually referring to a File. Strings are .. not Paths...

Answer (score 4):

As motivated by @Vogel612 I post my suggestion as an answer. An answer should probably contain a bit more than just a link to the [strategy pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm) therefore I'll adept the pattern to your presented code.

Instead of keeping the logic in the `Filter` class, this class is refactored to an interface which provides a simple `apply()` method.

```
public interface Filter {
    Conversation apply(Conversation conversation, String argumentValue);
}
```

If you need certain base logic you could also use an abstract base class instead of an interface of course.

A concrete implementation of a filter could now look like this:

```
public class UserFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public Conversation apply(Conversation conversation, String specificUser) {
        List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Filter by used id
        for (Message message : conversation.messages) {
            if (message.senderId.equals(specificUser)) {
                messageList.add(message);
                Conversation filteredConversation = 
                    new Conversation(conversation.name, messageList);
                conversation = filteredConversation;
            }
        }
        return conversation;
    }
}
```

This allows you to refactor the `filter` method to something like this:

```
private void filter(Filter filter, Conversation conversation, String outputFilePath) throws Exception {
    if (filter != null) {
        String argumentValue = filter.argumentValue;
        conv = filter.apply(conversation, argumentValue);
    }
    this.writeConversation(conversation, outputFilePath);
}
```

This also makes the `filterType` property redundant which thus can be removed. However, instead of keeping a single `Filter` class around, you need to create a concrete instance of a filter and pass it around. As you did not include the code where you set the `filterType`, I can't give more code on where the concrete object should be instantiated.

One advantage of the strategy pattern is, that it separates the implementation details into its own class and therefore allows switching strategies easily during runtime if needed. This also fosters the idea of one responsibility per class only.